Asymptotic Stability of Origin
I need to show that the origin is globally asymptotically stable for the system
$$x' =-x+2y-x^{3}+3x^{2}y-3xy^{2}\\
y' =-x+y-y^{3}$$
I thought that finding a Liapunov function would be easy, but it seems there's a lot of cross-terms. For instance, I've tried $V(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$, but there are many terms that appear that I am unsure about how to control.
Is there a way of seeing the general form of a Liapunov function that would show the origin is asymptotically stable? Is there a theorem I am missing I should use?

Well, playing with that specific candidate function in Desmos, it won't work, since you can't guarantee $\dot{V}$ will be nonpositive in a ball about the origin. Not that this really "helps" you reach a conclusion. I've tried a few examples with no luck, and (as far as I know) there is no real "general procedure" for creating these functions

A useful observation is that the substitution $v = x-y$ reduces the system to a much simpler one:
$$
v' = y-v^3, \qquad y' = -v-y^3.
$$
From here it is more obvious that $(v,y) = (0,0)$ is the only equilibrium, and that $V(v,y) = v^2 + y^2$ satisfies the requirements of a Lyapunov function, as
$$
V' = 2v(y-v^3) + 2y(-v-y^3) = -2(v^4 + y^4) < 0, \qquad  (v,y) \neq (0,0).
$$
